# How can I get stats on my votes for a particular period

Tags: discussion, statistics

I received an email today with the following message

> We recently noticed a substantial number of votes on your account to specific users. While we encourage everyone to upvote great posts and downvote bad ones, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in the merits of the post, not the person who wrote it. Please refrain from targeting specific users when voting.

I am certainly not targeting particular users.  Its possible that they had a spate of questions, and my votes skewed the stats.

Question: For my own interest, is there a way to get stats of my votes for a particular period?

Comment: Well... while the meta question you asked is a valid topic, I just got a confirmation from a CM that you might be looking at the wrong site (not Android.SE) ...

Comment: Quite right Andrew, it was Arduino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Votes are inherently private, thus only the user themselves can see their own votes (not even moderators).**

Individual votes can be seen on the profile:

- [Upvote](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=votes&sort=upvote)
- [Downvote](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=votes&sort=downvote)

However, there are no time filters, so the user has to manually group the time period on their own.

---

Meanwhile, the per-site's Users page also has [the Voters tab](https://android.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=quarter), broken down into weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly, and all-time (hover on the time period to check the actual period). However, the time period is always set to the latest and cannot be customized.